# How to return json data to a react state?

Tags: reactjs, json, express, web3js

I have a react component that makes a post to an express server (my own server). The server uses web3 to sign a transaction on `Ethereum`. Once the transaction is included in a block, a json object is returned to the server. It looks like this:

```
{ blockHash: '0xcd08039bac40e2865886e8f707ce9b901978c339d3abb81516787b0357f53fbd',
  blockNumber: 4611028,
 ...other data...
  transactionHash: '0x12c65523743ed169c764553ed2e0fb2af1710bb20a41b390276ffc2d5923c6a9',
  transactionIndex: 1 }
```

I need to store the `transactionHash` into the state of the above component. I have been searching for 2 days and am probably missing something very obvious.

Is this server-side or client-side code?

Do I need to learn and use async because of the inherent time delay in talking to Ethereum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the post request, you would have to perform this one the client via the componentDidMount, and then store the response as you would normally. You can find full examples here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html on the react page.

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => this.setState(response));
```

You would have to adjust the fetch operation to be a post request but you can find more information related to fetching here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/items", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => this.setState(response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Edit (example with Axios):

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => {
        const items = res.data;
        this.setState(items);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the lead. I am currently using axios so maybe I will need to modify. Just give me a day or two to accept. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I have gone and updated the example to contain the axios library.

Comment: Thank you, that did store `items` in the state. I am only wanting to store `transactionHash` and nothing more. Do you think I should open a separate question?

Comment: You can then just use JS dot notation to access the value. setState({ transaction: items.transactionHash });

Comment: That is not working unfortunately. I've opened a new thread which has got me down a rabbit hole...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749081/how-to-set-state-of-a-react-component-with-a-specific-item-from-a-returned-json/53749378#53749378