# How to set state of a react component with a specific item from a returned json object?

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, web3js

This is a follow up question to [How to return json data to a react state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737568/how-to-return-json-data-to-a-react-state)

My react component makes an `axios.post` to an Express server. The server uses web3js to sign a transaction onto Ethereum. Ethereum returns the following JSON object. Of note is that it takes some time (seconds to minutes depending on the miners) for the JSON to be returned:

```
{ blockHash: '0xcd08039bac40e2865886e8f707ce9b901978c339d3abb81516787b0357f53fbd',
  blockNumber: 4611028,
 ...other data...
  transactionHash: '0x12c65523743ed169c764553ed2e0fb2af1710bb20a41b390276ffc2d5923c6a9',
  transactionIndex: 1 }
```

Here is the code I am using to make the `axios.post` and set the state:

```
import React from "react";
import PaypalExpressBtn from "react-paypal-express-checkout";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Pay extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  items: {}
  };
 }

  render() {
    const onSuccess = payment => {
      axios
        .post("http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/", {
          value: this.props.value,
          fileName: this.props.fileName,
          hash: this.props.hash
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response.data))
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

      console.log(payment);
    };

    let env = "sandbox"; // you can set here to 'production' for production
    let currency = "USD"; // or you can set this value from your props or state
    let total = 3.33; // same as above, this is the total amount (based on 

    const client = {
      sandbox:
        "...key...",
      production: "YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <PaypalExpressBtn
          onSuccess={onSuccess}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run `console.log({ items: this.state.items})` it returns a seemingly endless array of constructors and props.

I have tried

`this.setState({ items : items.transactionHash });` and `console.log({ items: this.state.items.transactionHash})`, but neither worked.

What I need to do is `set.state` with only the `transactionHash` from the above JSON and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment

Destructuring operator is your friend

```
axios.post(
  "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users",
  {
    value: this.props.value,
    fileName: this.props.fileName,
    hash: this.props.hash
  }
)
.then(res => {
  const items = res.data;
  const {transactionHash} =items
  this.setState({ transactionHash });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`

Is this because it takes time to mine the block and return the json data? Do I need to `await` the json response before setting it to state?

Comment: please console.log(res.data) and add it to your question

Comment: I put this in the above comment, but console.log(res.data) does not return anything. I think the reason is that it takes some time for Ethereum to mine the transaction and return the json object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post(
    "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users", 
    {
        value: this.props.value,
        fileName: this.props.fileName,
        hash: this.props.hash
    }
)
.then(res => {
    const items = res.data;
    const { transactionHash } = items;
    this.setState({ 
        items: {
            transactionHash
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transactionHash' of null`

I think this has to do with Ethereum taking time to mine the transaction and return the json. Any idea how to wait for the json before setting the state?

Comment: Actually axios is doing this for you. The function callback in `then` is fired as soon as the response is sent from the server. Could you post what's in `res`?

Comment: `.then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
        });`


does not return anything...

Comment: It might be that you are returning early on the server side like you say. But this is out of scope for this issue.

Comment: I simplified the above code for clarity, this resolved the error but still generates no return. Thank you very much for your time and insight, I will start a new issue as much was answered here :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out where in the json object that transactionHash is located.

To find out the structure log the output first and examine the console.

```
console.log(res.data)
```

If the lets assume its under the data object eg:

```
"data: {
"transactionHash": "0x12c65523743ed169c764553ed2e0fb2af1710bb20a41b390276ffc2d5923c6a9"
}
```

This is how you would set the state:

```
axios.post(
  "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users",
  {
    value: this.props.value,
    fileName: this.props.fileName,
    hash: this.props.hash
  }
)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data)
  this.setState({ hash: res.data.transactionHash });
});
```

Tthe finished state would then be:

```
{
items: {},
hash: "0x12c65523743ed169c764553ed2e0fb2af1710bb20a41b390276ffc2d5923c6a9"

}
```

You can of course use destructuring but first we need to know the shape of the data that is coming back from the server

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see where you are going with it. `console.log(res.data)` has no return value. My assumption is that it takes 30 seconds or so for `Ethereum` to return the `json`. So there is no data to res.

I think that I need to await a response from `Ethereum` before logging and setting the state. I'm a bit out of my depth and have no idea how to do that! Any direction you could give me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 'then' part only happens when the response has returned. Do you get anything when you do console.log(res)?
have a look at chrome dev tools under the network tab. You should be able to find the request and see an error or a response: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Comment: Nothing is returned with `.then(res => {console.log(res)};`

Comment: Its hard to tell. You should post all your code in this function or better, post a link where we can see the code, e.g codepen or github

Comment: Thanks again, I edited. Will work on putting it on github if you think it will help.