# How to await a json return value (the return takes at least 30 seconds) before logging it? javascript/react/express

Tags: javascript, json, axios, ethereum, web3js

This is a follow up to these threads:

[How to set state of a react component with a specific item from a returned json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749081/how-to-set-state-of-a-react-component-with-a-specific-item-from-a-returned-json/53749329?noredirect=1#comment94352691_53749329)

[How to return json data to a react state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737568/how-to-return-json-data-to-a-react-state)

I am using web3js to sign a transaction on Ethereum, which then sends a JSON object with transaction data. The JSON takes at least 30 seconds to return.

I am trying to log the data with the following code:

```
axios.post(
    "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users", 
    {
        value: "value",
        fileName: "fileName",
        hash: "hash"
    }
)
.then(res => { console.log(res.data);});
```

There is no log appearing in the console.

The above is actually part of a bigger function, which I have made `async` and added `await`. This did not produce any results or errors:

```
const onSuccess = async payment => {
      axios.post(
        "http://ec2-54-67-28-69.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users",
        {
        value: "value",
        fileName: "fileName",
        hash: "hash"
        }
      );
      await (res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
```

I think the issue is that Ethereum takes some time to mine the transaction. I need to wait for the JSON response before logging it.

My Express server is having no issues, the JSON is successfully logged on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First block of code seems working, may be you want to attach `.catch` to it as error handler.

```js
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

In second part I think you are doing `await` wrong. You are awaiting on a function which never gets called. Await is supposed to be listening on something that gets called in below instance a promise returned by `axios`

```js
const samplePayload = {
  "userId": 100,
  "id": 100,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
};


// Using GET here for demo but you can swap it with POST
const onSuccess = async payment => {
  return await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", samplePayload
  ).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
}

console.log(onSuccess());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first code block is not working as intended because it is supposed to log res.data, and it is not. Thank you for taking the time to respond! Any other ideas of what could be going on?

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith try to open Network tab and see if API call is getting triggered. If it is then insert breakpoint on the response handler function. If you cant then add `debugger` in the function and inspect `res` value.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a little out of my depth here as `breakpoint` and `add debugger` are not familiar concepts. I will do some research and try to figure out what you are suggesting :)

The API is triggering, `console.log(res.data)` is returning a blank value to the console. I actually think the issue is with the server not returning the json object. That code looks like this:   `web3.eth
    .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
    .on("receipt", console.log, res.json());`

Answer (score 0):

Your second is wrong, you are never getting the response

```
const onSuccess = async payment => {
  const res = await axios.post(
    "http://ec2-54-67-28-69.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/users",
    {
    value: "value",
    fileName: "fileName",
    hash: "hash"
    }
  );
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data
}
```

Also, as Rikin said, your first code seems ok. Try adding the `.catch`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The first code does not log `res.data`....I wish it did :D

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith, did you try the catch? Also, did you try my code?

Comment: I did a .catch for error handling. I will do some research on what .catch does and if it will be helpful. Appreciate it :)