# How to have a server return a remote json object to client? react/express/web3

Tags: reactjs, express, web3js

I'm using web3 to send a transaction to Ethereum. My express server logs the block, transactionHash, etc. data as a JSON object. I need the JSON returned to the client.

This question is running the risk of repeating a previous question, but I believe that it is more refined, to the point, and ultimately a different question. These previous threads have helped me remove several errors from the code and zero in on what is actually happening.

[How to return json data to a react state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737568/how-to-return-json-data-to-a-react-state)

[How to await a json return value (the return takes at least 30 seconds) before logging it? javascript/react/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750439/how-to-await-a-json-return-value-the-return-takes-at-least-30-seconds-before-l)

[How to set state of a react component with a specific item from a returned json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749081/how-to-set-state-of-a-react-component-with-a-specific-item-from-a-returned-json/53749329?noredirect=1#comment94352691_53749329)

The specific code that is returning a blank value instead of the `json` object is:

```
web3.eth
  .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
  .on("receipt", console.log, res.json());
```

Client Code:

```
axios
   .post("http://ec2-54-67-28-69.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/")

   .then(response => console.log(response.data, payment))
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   })
```

I somehow need to get the JSON object inside the `res.json()` but putting it inside the function `()` does not work. Any suggestions?

I am pretty sure I need to use something from this:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x123...', data: '0x432...'})
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
web3.eth
   .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
   .on("receipt", res.json);
```

The way you did it `res.json()` was called without parameters.

Comment: returns a 404, thanks though. I think the solution is in the callbacks/promises structure. I am planning a database work around.