# How do I dynamically bind data model with "React" state?

Tags: c#, reactjs, model-binding

I have started learning React few day ago and I am little familiar with this, before that I was working with Angular for client side and .net core mvc with c# for server side.

Dynamic data binding with Html view as well as data validation, its look very comfortable when I used "Angular" but when I switch to "React" I become a blind. And

I could not find any way to bind data model with view on internet

what I have found?

```
class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

where user `this.state` has `user` which have two properties and those will be bind and validating with the view in a textbox like this:

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {!user.firstName &&
                        <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                    }
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {!user.lastName &&
                        <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                    }
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What I want?

```
public class UserModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Pass this .cs Data model with `this.state` and bind same with the view.

Is it possible with react, if yes then please provide the solution.

Comment: For enabling typing you should use `typescript`. You can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript). the rest is pretty much the same, I don't think in the stack of .net-angular also you pass anything from the server to the client as a model.

Comment: Thanks @Amir-Mousavi but this is not what I wanted to, may be I can not able to explain my needs properly

Comment: Well, probably! this is what I understood from your question :)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I just want to bind "cs" `UserModel` with React Client App

Comment: User in state is a simple object, not a model. You can implement it in a class with getter and setters but in react yor setter is setState() and your getter is a simple object retrieve from this.state

Comment: I don't think it is a wise decision, it brings the high coupling. probably you were able to do that with Angular cause you were using VS and creating everything as a single solution? but do not do that

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi yes, I knew that but it's a requirement :)

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Yes of-course but it can help me to archive what i want?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood well the op question:

```js
class UserModel {
   constructor(Id, FirstName, LastName) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LastName = LastName;
  }
  
   get id() {
     return this.Id;
   };
   
   get firstName() {
     return this.FirstName;
   };
   
   get lastName() {
     return this.LastName;
   };
   
   set id(newId) {
    this.Id = newId;   // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
   }
   
   set firstName(newName) {
    this.FirstName = newName;   // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
   }
   
   set lastName(newSurname) {
    this.LastName = newSurname;   // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
   }
   
   get instance() {
     return ({
        id: this.Id,
        firstName: this.FirstName,
        lastName: this.LastName,
     })
   }
}

const user = new UserModel(1, 'John', 'Doe');

console.log(user.id);
console.log(user.firstName);
console.log(user.lastName);
console.log(user.instance);
```

Comment: I thought https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737568/how-to-return-json-data-to-a-react-state this will help me

Comment: The answer you are referring to has nothing to do with sharing Data model between client and server. in that case, you should also have the state model locally in the client, otherwise `this.setState(response)` will throw an error as fields of state and response does not match. unless you want to create a new object in the state regardless of what the client expects, which is impossible with Typescript and can be done with JS only

Comment: Thanks both of you, I am implementing what you have given to me with my needs. Once done I will post the answer